# How I can move file on a SFTP server in PHP

Tags: php, sftp

How can I move a file from one directory into another directory?

I have try this, but it doesn't work:

```
$success = @rename('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . $path_from, 'ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . $path_to);
if ($success) {
    echo "moving success!";
}else {
    echo "moving failed!";
}
```

I'm using PHP SSH2 functions.

Can someone help me?

Comment: FYI, the `@` operator is hiding any possibly helpful error message you might be getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ssh2_sftp_rename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp-rename.php):

```
ssh2_sftp_rename($sftp, $path_from, $path_to);
```

Assuming both variables contain full paths to files, e.g. like:

```
$path_from = "/source/directory/myfile.txt";
$path_to = "/destination/directory/myfile.txt";
```